# React/js- copy array and edit without editing original array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to filter an array, pass results in new array and edit new array without changes in the original array.

Code looks like this:

```js
const personalDocs = [{
    "IDcard": false,
    "passport": true,
    "documentnumber": "1",
    "dateofissue": ""
}, 
{
  "IDcard": true,
  "passport": false,
  "documentnumber": "2",
  "dateofissue": ""
}];


  const passports = personalDocs.filter((doc) => doc.passport === true);

           const passportsCollection = [...passports];
// tried:  const passportsCollection = passports.slice()

            passportsColection.forEach(object => {
              delete object['IDcard'];
              object.taken = "YES";
          });
 
        console.log("ALL PERSONAL DOCS:")
        console.log(personalDocs)      // this becomes same as passportsCollection :(
        console.log("JUST PASSPORTS")
        console.log(passportsCollection)
```

Live code available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wilson-p9w8kt?file=/src/App.js

Is this related to javascripts basics or react?

Thank you.

Comment: The issue here is that you are creating a new container array reference, but all of the objects inside are their original reference. You'd need to do what's called a "deep copy"

Comment: @mhodges Thanks for explaining the essence of the problem. Whis will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` directly with `filter` instead of `forEach` in order to create a new array. you can destruct the object  to remove `IDcard` instead of using `delete` keyword

```
.map(({
  IDcard,
  ...object
})
```

See snippet below

```js
const personalDocs = [{
    IDcard: false,
    passport: true,
    documentnumber: "1",
    dateofissue: ""
  },
  {
    IDcard: true,
    passport: false,
    documentnumber: "2",
    dateofissue: ""
  }
];

const passports = personalDocs.filter(doc => doc.passport).map(({
  IDcard,
  ...object
}) => ({ ...object,
  taken: 'YES'
}));

console.log("ALL PERSONAL DOCS:");
console.log(personalDocs);
console.log("JUST PASSPORTS");
console.log(passports);
```

Answer (score 3):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```js
const passportsCollection = [...passports];
```

It doesn't clone the items. It creates a copy of the array, but with references to the same objects.

Why? Because objects are passed by reference. So each item in each of the two arrays will be a reference to the same (base) object.

To clone the objects you need to spread each of them:

```js
const passportsCollection = passports.map(i => ({ ...i }));
```

See it working:

```js
const personalDocs = [{
    "IDcard": false,
    "passport": true,
    "documentnumber": "1",
    "dateofissue": ""
  },
  {
    "IDcard": true,
    "passport": false,
    "documentnumber": "2",
    "dateofissue": ""
  }
];


const passports = personalDocs.filter((doc) => doc.passport === true);

const passportsCollection = passports.map(i => ({ ...i }));
// tried:  const passportsCollection = passports.slice()

passportsCollection.forEach(object => {
  delete object['IDcard'];
  object.taken = "YES";
});

console.log("ALL PERSONAL DOCS:")
console.log(personalDocs) // this becomes same as passportsCollection :(
console.log("JUST PASSPORTS")
console.log(passportsCollection)
```

Another problem you had was you missed an `l` when typing `passportsCollection`.

---

On a separate note, what you're doing could be streamlined to:

```js
const passportsCollection = personalDocs
  .filter(o => o.passport)
  .map(({ IDcard, ...o }) => ({ ...o, taken: 'YES'}))
```

```js
const personalDocs = [{
    "IDcard": false,
    "passport": true,
    "documentnumber": "1",
    "dateofissue": ""
  },
  {
    "IDcard": true,
    "passport": false,
    "documentnumber": "2",
    "dateofissue": ""
  }
];

console.log({
  personalDocs,
  passportsCollection: personalDocs
    .filter(o => o.passport)
    .map(({ IDcard, ...o }) => ({ ...o, taken: 'YES'}))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's related to JavaScript basics.

You copied the array, but you didn't copied the object inside of the array.

```
const copy = passports.map(object => ({ ...object})
```

Notice that `.map` and `.filter` already create a copy of an array so you don't need to do `[...passports]

You can also try using [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Comment: `structuredClone` is not available in all browsers. So spread operator is the best solution

Comment: @PavanJadda in Internet Explorer which is officially dead and Samsung internet which nobody uses, but yes